# Google Translate asks for Flash

Tags: flash, google-translate

Whenever I use Google Translate I get a notification about Adobe Flash being disabled:

[image: Google Translate - Adobe Flash]

Things seem to work normally without Flash, so I don't understand why the translator is even trying to use it. Is there some Flash-based functionality I'm missing? Would Google Translate be faster or more accurate with Flash enabled?

I've tried searching [flash](https://support.google.com/translate/toolkit/search?hl=en&query=flash) in Google Translate Help but it did not match any answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Google Translate page uses Flash to play the sounds of the words being translated:

[image]

So you only have to worry about it if you want to hear the words.